# Pass real object and mock object in constructor

Tags: java, mockito

I have a `AccountDetails` constructor as below.

```
private final AccountDetailsRestClient accountDetailsRestClient;
private final ConstantMapService constantMapService; 

private CalculationMap calculationMap;

public AccountDetails(final AccountDetailsRestClient accountDetailsRestClient, final ConstantMapService constantMapService) {
    this.accountDetailsRestClient = accountDetailsRestClient;
    this.constantMapService = constantMapService;
    initializeConstantsData();
}

private void initializeConstantsData() {
    if (this.calculationMap == null) {
        this.calculationMap = constantMapService.getMap(java.time.LocalDate.now());
    }
}
```

Using Mockito I am unable to initialize all 3 objects accountDetailsRestClient, constantMapService, calculationMap. If accountDetailsRestClient is not null then constantMapService is null or vice versa.

Mockito test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class AccountDetailsTest {
    
        @Mock
        private AccountDetailsRestClient accountDetailsRestClient;
    
        @Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
        private CalculationMap calculationMap;
    
        @InjectMocks
        private final AccountDetails sut = new AccountDetailsTestImpl(new ConstantMapServiceMock());

       @Test
        public void testMethod() {
            //left it blank to check constructor issue first
        }
    
        class AccountDetailsTestImpl extends AccountDetails {
            AccountDetailsTestImpl(final ConstantMapService constantMapService) {
                    super(accountDetailsRestClient, constantMapService);
                }
            }
    
    }
```

But the accountDetailsRestClient is now null in the constructor.

How can I solve this issue without using PowerMock. Either by changing the code in the class or by changing the mockito test class?

Comment: Using Mockito.mock() instead of @Mock for restClient solved the issue. And use AccountDetails directly for initializing ‘sut’ instead of using AccountDetailsTestImpl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `@InjectMocks` and simply do things by hand, like you almost are already:

```
AccountDetails sut = new AccountDetails(mockDependency, realObject);
```

Since `@Mock` and similar auto-wiring have to happen after the class is instantiated, if you need to refer to a mock during initialization, create it programmatically:

```
AccountDetailsRestClient mockRestClient = mock(AccountDetailsRestClient.class);
```

Comment: The rest client is null in constructor in that case. If I do the initialization of `sut` using `@Before` method then restClient is not null but constantMapService object is null

Comment: @firstpostcommenter Depending on how things are sequenced, you may need to slightly reduce the magic: `AccountDetailsRestClient mockRestClient = mock(AccountDetailsRestClient.class);`

Comment: Thanks. That solved the issue. I thought that @Mock and Mockito.mock() are same

Comment: @firstpostcommenter They invoke the same logic, but `@Mock` is a post-processing step (at which point you may have already tried to use the not-yet-initialized mocks).

Comment: Is this behaviour(i.e. @Mock happens after the class is instantiated) documented anywhere?